# is their anyway of running a docker container client side in an application without installing docker on the device?

Tags: python, docker, containers

I am new to docker so if the answer is obvious I am sorry.

I am wanting my application (written in python) to run a tool that is available in a Linux environment that isn't available in windows and am wondering if using docker is an option because I understand the very basics.

Comment: Docker containers are built with the sole purpose of running inside a docker environment. It may be possible to reverse-engineer the process, but doing so could have un-intended consequences. You do have the option to install Docker on Windows, but it will create a virtual server that runs a linux environment (or requires a WSL layer in your windows install) to do so.

Answer (score 1):

May be what you need is Windows Subsystem for Linux - WSL, see details here on how to start:
[Windows Subsystem for Linux Installation Guide for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is a detailed version of above answer from @Stephen)

In short - yes, you can put DockerDesktop in your Windows machine.

Visit https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop for downloading the same.

Give this a read for detailed steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers

Once you have it running on your Windows machine, you can deploy any linux on your docker container (which is running on Windows).
You may use this page for reference - https://runnable.com/docker/install-docker-on-linux

Once you have the required Linux environment, proceed to install your application on the same.